# Get combinations of multiple columns (Cartesian product) of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, combinations, combinatorics, cartesian-product

So I have a dataframe representing various model estimates for the likelihood of each of a group of candidates winning an election.

```
             Steve     John      
    Model1   0.327586  0.289474 
    Model2   0.322581  0.285714 
    Model3   0.303030  0.294118
```

**I want a dataframe representing all of the combinations of model values across columns, i.e. Cartesian product of all columns**. So the above would be transformed to the below.

```
             model Steve     value Steve    model John     value John     
    0        Model1          0.327586       Model1         0.289474
    1        Model1          0.327586       Model2         0.285714
    2        Model1          0.327586       Model3         0.294118
    3        Model2          0.322581       Model1         0.289474
    4        Model2          0.322581       Model2         0.285714
    5        Model2          0.322581       Model3         0.294118
    6        Model3          0.303030       Model1         0.289474
    7        Model3          0.303030       Model2         0.285714
    8        Model3          0.303030       Model3         0.294118
```

The above is the simple case, but in theory I would like to be able to do this for N models and M candidates, resulting in a dataframe with N^M rows and 2M columns (in practice N < 20, M < 6).

In searching for an answer I've seen a lot of recommendations for the `itertools` module for stuff like this, but couldn't figure out how to get all of the combinations across multiple lists (`itertools.combinations` seems to only work for finding all of the combinations within a single list).

Comment: So need only solution for 2 columns? So please remove `I would like to be able to do this for N models and M canditates` from your question, because accepted answer working with `2 columns` only. Or something missing?

Comment: You mean [Cartesian-product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cartesian-product). I added that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always better to provide the code so that we can create a frame quickly, not just a table. Any way you can create a common `key` and can do database like cross join to get the final result. You can do it in one line but I am doing step by step.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'model': ['model1', 'model2'],
                   'steve': ['a', 'b'],
                   'jhon': ['c', 'd']
                  })

# create a common key

df['key'] = 'xyz'

# create two seperate dataframe for self join
# but it is possible to use the direct operation (right side) in 
# inside of merge funciton

df_steve = df [['model', 'steve', 'key']]
df_jhon = df [['model', 'jhon', 'key']]

# self join    
pd.merge(df_steve, df_jhon, on='key', suffixes=('_steve', '_jhon')).drop('key', axis=1)
```

output:

```
  model_steve steve model_jhon jhon
0      model1     a     model1    c
1      model1     a     model2    d
2      model2     b     model1    c
3      model2     b     model2    d
```

One liner Code:

```
cross_df = pd.merge(df[['model', 'steve', 'key']], 
                    df[['model', 'jhon', 'key']], 
                    on='key', 
                    suffixes=('_steve', '_jhon')
                    ).drop('key', axis=1)
```

*just change the column name according to your need.*

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
from  itertools import product

#get all combinations of all columns
a = product(*[zip(df.index, x) for x in df.T.values])
#create new columns names
cols = [c for x in df.columns for c in ('model_' + x, 'value_' + x)]
#flattening nested lists with DataFrame contructor
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[y for x in z for y in x] for z in a], columns=cols)
print (df1)
  model_Steve  value_Steve model_John  value_John
0      Model1     0.327586     Model1    0.289474
1      Model1     0.327586     Model2    0.285714
2      Model1     0.327586     Model3    0.294118
3      Model2     0.322581     Model1    0.289474
4      Model2     0.322581     Model2    0.285714
5      Model2     0.322581     Model3    0.294118
6      Model3     0.303030     Model1    0.289474
7      Model3     0.303030     Model2    0.285714
8      Model3     0.303030     Model3    0.294118
```